# android menu to start game

Tags: android, menu

So I created most of the game I am working on but I have not done the menu yet..I figured I would look at that last.  For the menu my idea is to have a :

```
setContentView(R.layout.menu);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Both being in the Oncreate method, but is that possible?  Is the menu meant to be its own .xml file and can you go from one layout to another or is that a bad idea?  I think I am confused on how things transition from menu to game.  The idea is in the menu you have "Exit" and "newgame" and when you click the newgame button it should start/run/continue the rest of the application..which confuses me a bit.  Can one and should one create a menu class and build it all from there?  If you used a different class how would your mainactivity know when it is ready to run the game itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have 1 content view at a time.  If you call it twice in onCreate like that, the first layout will be created then overwritten and will never be shown.

While you could change layouts within an Activity, the normal thing to do here would be to create the menu as 1 Activity and the game itself as a second Activity.  So when they click the "New Game" item, it launches the game Activity.